# How does Github releases generate archive filenames?

Tags: git, curl, github

I just created releases for my NFQL software on github.
Here is the releases page: https://github.com/vbajpai/nfql/releases

For the latest release, `v0.7`. If I click on the tarball button, it saves a `nfql-0.7.tar.gz`. This is great and exactly how I want my release archives to be named.

[image]

However, I need the download link of the tarball itself. So that I can create a MacPorts/Homebrew file for the tarball. If I look at the download link, it is:

a) https://github.com/vbajpai/nfql/archive/v0.7.tar.gz or
b) https://codeload.github.com/vbajpai/nfql/tar.gz/v0.7

now if I use `curl/wget` it saves the tarball as `v0.7.tar.gz`. I know I can specify a filename while downloading using `curl/wget`. I want to know is there is a reliable github URL I can use to fetch my tarball as `nfql-0.7.tar.gz`.

PS: What is github doing there anyway? How is the filename altered by the browsers when I directly click the source code link?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first link gives a redirection to the second one:

```
curl --head https://github.com/vbajpai/nfql/archive/v0.7.tar.gz
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://codeload.github.com/vbajpai/nfql/tar.gz/v0.7
...
```

> How is the filename altered by the browsers when I directly click the
>   source code link?

The filename is defined via a custom `Content-Disposition` HTTP header:

```
curl --head https://codeload.github.com/vbajpai/nfql/tar.gz/v0.7
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=nfql-0.7.tar.gz
...
```

So you can use `curl`'s `-O, --remote-name`, `-L, --location` and `-J, --remote-header-name` to (resp.) write output to a file named as the remote file, follow redirects and use the header-provided filename:

```
curl -LOJ https://github.com/vbajpai/nfql/archive/v0.7.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this worked when the question was originally posted, but now you can use https://github.com/vbajpai/nfql/archive/v0.7/nfql-0.7.tar.gz to get the correct filename directly without looking at headers. This is very nice when using wget as you need no flags, just simply `wget https://github.com/vbajpai/nfql/archive/v0.7/nfql-0.7.tar.gz`

Note that it is the next-to-last path component that selects the release to use - you can put whatever filename you want to have as the last path component.

Comment: This is great. I'm sure this is documented somewhere but I couldn't find it. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to always work. e.g. this one does not: `https://github.com/FreePBX/restart/archive/v13.0.7/restart-13.0.7.tar.gz` but I haven't figured out what's different about it. Playing around a bit I got this to work instead: `https://github.com/FreePBX/restart/archive/release/13.0.7/restart-release-13.0.7.tar.gz`

Comment: @miken32 Sure it works. Read the last paragraph of my answer again. In the nfql example the "release to use" is `v0.7`, while in your example the "release to use" is `release/13.0.7` - the difference is only in the tagging scheme used by the projects.