# GitHub: How to rename the folder inside a downloaded Zip File?

Tags: git, github

I want a specific Name to be given when someone Downloads the Zip Package from my GitHub Repo.

My Problem is: the Name must have an appended Version Number like `My_File_1.0.2`.
But GitHub automagically generates the Name from the Repo name.

As a Workaround, I can only think of using multiple branches, but that is a hell of a mess to deal with.
Isn't there a better way to do this? I am thinking of some sort of config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create that archive file yourself (with the right naming convention) and [add it as a release](https://help.github.com/articles/about-releases/) to your tag.

That tag already references the zip/tgz of the repo, but using a naming convention which does not suit you, [as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20774727/6309).